# Android : Ksoap2 SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap-env:Server' faultstring: 'Processing Error. More details in WS Error Log'

Tags: android, wsdl, android-ksoap2, soapfault

I am using KSoap2 to access SAP web service.

below is my code

```
package com.example.getcustomerwsdl;


public class GetCustomerActivity extends Activity {

    static final int CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "SdRfcCustomerGet";

    private static final String WS_NAMESPACE = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";

    private static final String WS_METHOD_NAME = "SdRfcCustomerGet";

    private static final String soapAction = WS_NAMESPACE + "/"+ WS_METHOD_NAME;

    private static final String WSDL_URL = "http://IP:8010/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zcustomer_get2/200/zcustomer_get2/zcustomer_get2?sap-user=*******&sap-password=*******";

    String result = null;

    TextView responseTxtView;

    ItemObject C;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_customer);

        responseTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        new GetUCustomerTask().execute();
    }

    private class GetUCustomerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showDialog(CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final String str = null;
            String output = null;
            AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = null;
            try {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WS_NAMESPACE,
                        WS_METHOD_NAME);

                ItemObject items = new ItemObject();

                items = new ItemObject("","","","","","","","","");

                CustomerObject custT = new CustomerObject(items);
                custT.item = items;

                PropertyInfo pinfoCustomer = new PropertyInfo();
                pinfoCustomer.setName("CustomerT");
                pinfoCustomer.setValue(custT);
                pinfoCustomer.setType(custT.getClass());

                request.addProperty(pinfoCustomer);

                PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                pi.setName("Kunnr");
                pi.setValue("0000491100");
                pi.setType(String.class);

                request.addProperty(pi);

                PropertyInfo pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
                pi3.setName("Name1");
                pi3.setValue("");
                pi3.setType(String.class);

                request.addProperty(pi3);

                MarshalBase64 mbase = new MarshalBase64();

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENV;
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.implicitTypes = true;              
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  

                envelope.addMapping(WS_NAMESPACE, "CustomerT",new CustomerObject().getClass());

                androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(WSDL_URL);

                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

                mbase.register(envelope);

                androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);

                Log.d(TAG, "HTTP REQUEST1:\n"
                        + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                Log.d(TAG, "HTTP RESPONSE1:\n"
                        + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

                 if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                        String strn= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                        Log.i("SoapFault", strn);

                    } else {
                        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                        Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
                    }

                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                C.Kunnr = response.getProperty(0)
                        .toString();
                C.Anred = response.getProperty(1).toString();
                C.Name1 = (String) response.getProperty(2).toString();
                C.Pfach = (String) response.getProperty(3).toString();
                C.Stras = (String) response.getProperty(4).toString();
                C.Pstlz = (String) response.getProperty(5).toString();
                C.Telf1 = (String) response.getProperty(6).toString();
                C.Telfx = (String) response.getProperty(7).toString();
                C.Ort01 = (String) response.getProperty(8).toString();

                Log.d(TAG, "HTTP response:\n" + response);

                final SoapPrimitive resp = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                        .getResponse();

                Log.d(TAG, "HTTP resp:\n" + resp);

                SoapObject resonse = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

                output = resonse.toString();

                Log.d(TAG, "HTTP REQUEST2:\n"
                        + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                Log.d(TAG, "HTTP RESPONSE2:\n"
                        + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

                Log.d(TAG, "output:\n" + resonse.getProperty(0).toString());

                result = output;

                if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) { // SoapObject =
                    // SUCCESS
                    SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                } else if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                    SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
                    try {
                        soapFault.getMessage();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("HTTP REQUESTEXP:\n"
                        + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                System.out.println("HTTP RESPONSEEXP:\n"
                        + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String response) {
            removeDialog(CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    responseTxtView.setText("response " + result);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "response" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {
        case CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG: {
            ProgressDialog loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            loadingDialog.setMessage("Connecting");
            loadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
            return loadingDialog;
        }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

CustomerObject class

```
package com.example.getcustomerwsdl;


public class CustomerObject implements KvmSerializable {

    ItemObject item;
    public CustomerObject() {
    }

    public CustomerObject(ItemObject item) {
        super();
        this.item = item;
    }

    public ItemObject getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(ItemObject item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            info.type = ItemObject.class;
            info.name = "item";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            item =  (ItemObject) value;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

ItemObject class

```
package com.example.getcustomerwsdl;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class ItemObject implements KvmSerializable {

    String Kunnr;
    String Anred;
    String Name1;
    String Pfach;
    String Stras;
    String Pstlz;
    String Telf1;
    String Telfx;
    String Ort01;

    public ItemObject() {
        super();
    }

    public ItemObject(String kunnr, String anred, String name1,
            String pfach, String stras, String pstlz, String telf1,
            String telfx, String ort01) {
        super();
        Kunnr = kunnr;
        Anred = anred;
        Name1 = name1;
        Pfach = pfach;
        Stras = stras;
        Pstlz = pstlz;
        Telf1 = telf1;
        Telfx = telfx;
        Ort01 = ort01;
    }

    public String getKunnr() {
        return Kunnr;
    }

    public void setKunnr(String kunnr) {
        Kunnr = kunnr;
    }

    public String getAnred() {
        return Anred;
    }

    public void setAnred(String anred) {
        Anred = anred;
    }

    public String getName1() {
        return Name1;
    }

    public void setName1(String name1) {
        Name1 = name1;
    }

    public String getPfach() {
        return Pfach;
    }

    public void setPfach(String pfach) {
        Pfach = pfach;
    }

    public String getStras() {
        return Stras;
    }

    public void setStras(String stras) {
        Stras = stras;
    }

    public String getPstlz() {
        return Pstlz;
    }

    public void setPstlz(String pstlz) {
        Pstlz = pstlz;
    }

    public String getTelf1() {
        return Telf1;
    }

    public void setTelf1(String telf1) {
        Telf1 = telf1;
    }

    public String getTelfx() {
        return Telfx;
    }

    public void setTelfx(String telfx) {
        Telfx = telfx;
    }

    public String getOrt01() {
        return Ort01;
    }

    public void setOrt01(String ort01) {
        Ort01 = ort01;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {

        case 0:
            return Kunnr;
        case 1:
            return Anred;
        case 2:
            return Name1;
        case 3:
            return Pfach;
        case 4:
            return Stras;
        case 5:
            return Pstlz;
        case 6:
            return Telf1;
        case 7:
            return Telfx;
        case 8:
            return Ort01;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Kunnr";
            break;
        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Anred";
            break;
        case 2:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Name1";
            break;
        case 3:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Pfach";
            break;
        case 4:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Stras";
            break;
        case 5:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Pstlz";
            break;
        case 6:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Telf1";
            break;
        case 7:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Telfx";
            break;
        case 8:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Ort01";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            Kunnr = value.toString();
            break;
        case 1:
            Anred = value.toString();
            break;
        case 2:
            Name1 = value.toString();
            break;
        case 3:
            Pfach = value.toString();
            break;
        case 4:
            Stras = value.toString();
            break;
        case 5:
            Pstlz = value.toString();
            break;
        case 6:
            Telf1 = value.toString();
            break;
        case 7:
            Telfx = value.toString();
            break;
        case 8:
            Ort01 = value.toString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

below is my target Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<sapsess:Session xmlns:sapsess="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">
<enableSession>true</enableSession>
</sapsess:Session>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:SdRfcCustomerGet xmlns:ns1='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>
<CustomerT>
<item>
<Kunnr></Kunnr>
<Anred></Anred>
<Name1></Name1>
<Pfach></Pfach>
<Stras></Stras>
<Pstlz></Pstlz>
<Ort01></Ort01>
<Telf1></Telf1>
<Telfx></Telfx>
</item>
</CustomerT>
<Kunnr>0000491100</Kunnr>
<Name1></Name1>
</ns1:SdRfcCustomerGet>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is my target response

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
<n0:SdRfcCustomerGetResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<CustomerT>
<item>
<Kunnr>0000491100</Kunnr>
<Anred/>
<Name1>Customer Company 02</Name1>
<Pfach>127 353</Pfach>
<Stras>Sheikh Zayed Road</Stras>
<Pstlz/>
<Ort01>Berlin</Ort01>
<Telf1/>
<Telfx/>
</item>
</CustomerT>
</n0:SdRfcCustomerGetResponse>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

i get the following error

```
11-27 14:30:38.290: I/SoapFault(24418): Processing Error. More details in WS Error Log (transaction SRT_UTIL) by selection with UTC timestamp 20131127102016 
11-27 14:30:38.310: W/System.err(24418): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap-env:Server' faultstring: 'Processing Error. More details in WS Error Log (transaction SRT_UTIL) by selection with UTC timestamp 20131127102016 ' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@42b68288
11-27 14:30:38.310: W/System.err(24418):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:112)
11-27 14:30:38.310: W/System.err(24418):    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
11-27 14:30:38.310: W/System.err(24418):    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at com.example.getcustomerwsdl.GetCustomerActivity$GetUCustomerTask.doInBackground(GetCustomerActivity.java:130)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at com.example.getcustomerwsdl.GetCustomerActivity$GetUCustomerTask.doInBackground(GetCustomerActivity.java:1)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-27 14:30:38.315: W/System.err(24418):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

this is the request sent to the web service from my code

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<SdRfcCustomerGet xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" id="o0" c:root="1">
<CustomerT>
<item>
<Kunnr></Kunnr>
<Anred></Anred>
<Name1></Name1>
<Pfach></Pfach>
<Stras></Stras>
<Pstlz></Pstlz>
<Telf1></Telf1>
<Telfx></Telfx>
<Ort01></Ort01>
</item>
</CustomerT>
<Kunnr>0000491100</Kunnr>
<Name1></Name1>
</SdRfcCustomerGet>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

this is the response i get

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
<soap-env:Fault>
<faultcode>soap-env:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en">
Processing Error. More details in WS Error Log (transaction SRT_UTIL) by selection with UTC timestamp 20131127102016 
</faultstring>
<detail/>
</soap-env:Fault>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

this is my WSDL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
 <wsdl:documentation>
  <sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl="http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl"/>
 </wsdl:documentation>
 <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
 <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IF_IF_ZCUSTOMER_GET2">
  <sapsession:Session xmlns:sapsession="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">
   <sapsession:enableSession>false</sapsession:enableSession>
  </sapsession:Session>
 </wsp:Policy>
 <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_IF_OP_SdRfcCustomerGet">
  <sapblock:enableBlocking xmlns:sapblock="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/blocking/">true</sapblock:enableBlocking>
  <sapcomhnd:enableCommit xmlns:sapcomhnd="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/commit/">false</sapcomhnd:enableCommit>
  <saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required>
  <saprmnw05:enableWSRM xmlns:saprmnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/wsrm/">false</saprmnw05:enableWSRM>
 </wsp:Policy>
 <wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
   <xsd:simpleType name="char10">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="char15">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="char16">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:maxLength value="16"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="char31">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:maxLength value="31"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="char35">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:maxLength value="35"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:schema>
  <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
   <xsd:import namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"/>
   <xsd:simpleType name="RfcException.Message.Number">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
     <xsd:pattern value="\d*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:complexType name="Rfccust">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Kunnr" type="n0:char10"/>
     <xsd:element name="Anred" type="n0:char15"/>
     <xsd:element name="Name1" type="n0:char35"/>
     <xsd:element name="Pfach" type="n0:char10"/>
     <xsd:element name="Stras" type="n0:char35"/>
     <xsd:element name="Pstlz" type="n0:char10"/>
     <xsd:element name="Ort01" type="n0:char35"/>
     <xsd:element name="Telf1" type="n0:char16"/>
     <xsd:element name="Telfx" type="n0:char31"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="RfcException.Message">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Number" type="tns:RfcException.Message.Number"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="SdRfcCustomerGet.RfcException">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Name" type="tns:SdRfcCustomerGet.RfcExceptions"/>
     <xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xsd:element name="Message" type="tns:RfcException.Message" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="TableOfRfccust">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:Rfccust" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="SdRfcCustomerGet.RfcExceptions">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="NothingSpecified"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="NoRecordFound"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:element name="SdRfcCustomerGet.Exception" type="tns:SdRfcCustomerGet.RfcException"/>
   <xsd:element name="SdRfcCustomerGet">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="CustomerT" type="tns:TableOfRfccust"/>
      <xsd:element name="Kunnr" type="n0:char10" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="Name1" type="n0:char35" minOccurs="0"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
   <xsd:element name="SdRfcCustomerGetResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="CustomerT" type="tns:TableOfRfccust"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
 <wsdl:message name="SdRfcCustomerGet">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SdRfcCustomerGet"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="SdRfcCustomerGetResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:SdRfcCustomerGetResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="SdRfcCustomerGet.Exception">
  <wsdl:part name="SdRfcCustomerGet.Exception" element="tns:SdRfcCustomerGet.Exception"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:portType name="ZCUSTOMER_GET2">
  <wsdl:documentation>
   <sapdoc:sapdoc xmlns:sapdoc="urn:sap:esi:documentation">
    <sapdoc:docitem docURL="http://IP:8010/sap/bc/esdt/docu/sd_text?sap-client=200&amp;sd_name=ZCUSTOMER_GET2"/>
   </sapdoc:sapdoc>
  </wsdl:documentation>
  <wsp:Policy>
   <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#IF_IF_ZCUSTOMER_GET2"/>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:operation name="SdRfcCustomerGet">
   <wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_IF_OP_SdRfcCustomerGet"/>
   </wsp:Policy>
   <wsdl:input message="tns:SdRfcCustomerGet"/>
   <wsdl:output message="tns:SdRfcCustomerGetResponse"/>
   <wsdl:fault name="SdRfcCustomerGet.Exception" message="tns:SdRfcCustomerGet.Exception"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I cant find out why don't i get the response from the webservice...can anyone help me with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is explicit. Your webservice is producing an error message about it that happened on the server!

I would suggest to test the request/response with something like SOAPUI and debug the server.